# QFile write does not respond / crashes the application

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I'm working on embedded linux and copying files to usb flash drives.

my files:

```
sourceFile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
targetFile->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

the variables

```
nCopySize = sourceFile->size() / 100;
QByteArray buffer;
```

and the read write part:

```
//copy files
for (int count = 0; !(buffer = sourceFile->read(nCopySize + 1)).isEmpty(); count+=(nCopySize + 1))
{
    try {
        int writeErr = targetFile->write(buffer);

        qDebug() << writeErr;
        if (writeErr == -1) { //e.g. when device is plugged off
            abortCopyFile = true;
        }
    } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        qDebug() << "catched something:" << ex.what();
        //abort copying file... etc.
    } catch (...) {
        qDebug() << "catched something else";
        //abort copying file... etc.
    }

    //report progress ...

    //abort-option
    if (abortCopyFile == true)
        break;
}
```

I don't know if the `catch` part is right, but that's not my actual question. The point is, that when I unplug the USB flash drive while copying the file from the system to the USB flash drive, the line

```
targetFile->write(buffer);
```

sometimes responds `-1` and sometimes it responds not at all and the application kinda crashes ominously.

So I thought the `try-catch` would help me but it doesn't. It does not catch anything. The app just crashes.

What can I do about that problem? Restarting the application is the least I want to do.

Comment: Does your embedded Linux has udev? You could then watch your usb device for removal event. Also move your abortCopyFile check into try condition, check it before trying to write domething in file, and set abortCopyFile to true in catch conditions too. You may also try QFileSystemWatcher to watch your usb device if your usb device are block device

Comment: have udev installed. But I do mounting and stuff with usbmount.

Comment: Try watching /media folder for changes with QFileSystemWatcher. Maybe it will be enough for you.

Comment: I added a `if (targetFile->exists())` and that triggers well :) and a good amount of loops before the application crashes from `targetFile->write(buffer)`. I might test this with a higher buffer size / bigger file

Comment: with 8MB file it crashes ominously after reporting `-1`. This is so weird :/ And it says, that the file does still exist right before writing.

Comment: Not sure, but exist() will be true if you have already opened the file. Another way is to open file each time you need to write it and "seek" to the rigth position. But if you do writing in for loop it is really not that good idea. Try watching mounted folder with QFileSystemWatcher. or check if file exist with QFileInfo on each for loop iteration, it is at least faster then reopening file each time you want to write it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189824/discussion-between-michael1248-and-xplatforms).

Comment: `QFile` does not throw exceptions (at least by Qt itself). If you want exceptions, you have to throw them yourself (just be sure to not let them leak to Qt event loop, unless you want the program to terminate in an ugly way). But probably better to just go about this using normal Qt ways.